# Какие языки необходимо знать для этого?

Tags: любой-язык

Здравствуйте. Хочу сделать такую форму:
человек вводит город, откуда хочет приехать и до куда добраться и ему высвечивается список людей, которые едут туда же.

У каждого из этих людей есть определенный рейтинг, который выставляется посетителями.

Какой/какие языки необходимо знать для этого?

Comment: Любой\любые

Answer (score 10):

Позволю себе дополнить поистине всеобъемлющий комментарий [@DreamChild](/users/10162/dreamchild) и ответ [@sergiks](/users/7161/sergiks). Он явно имел ввиду, что любой язык программирования, обладающий полнотой по Тьюрингу (а это любой из существующих неэзотерических языков программирования), пригоден для решения описанной вами задачи. Однако, в зависимости от конкретной задачи, стоит делать выбор в пользу конкретного языка.

Если вы планируете сделать веб-приложение, вам стоит использовать Java, Python, Ruby или PHP (не рекомендую, но справедливости ради его стоит упомянуть). К тому же, для создания веб-приложения однозначно понадобятся знания HTML, CSS и JavaScript. Также для хранения данных в веб-приложениях обычно используют базы данных, поэтому нужно знать SQL и уметь работать с какой-нибудь СУБД (MySQL, например).

Если планируется десктопное приложение, то стоит для начала уточнить, на каких платформах оно будет запускаться, и выбирать язык программирования исходя из этого. Судя по фразе "*У каждого из этих людей есть определенный рейтинг, который выставляется посетителями*", необходимо реализовать клиент-серверное приложение, причём клиент и сервер можно реализовать на разных языках. Для сервера подошла бы Java, для клиента можно использовать C++ (в сочетании с какой-нибудь библиотекой для построения пользовательского интерфейса вроде Qt), Java (на ней десктопные приложения пишут редко, но всё же пишут), C# (тут вы ограничиваете себя только ОС Windows, реализация .Net под Linux сильно отстаёт от своего прародителя), Delphi.

Если вы планируете писать приложение под мобильные платформы - вам нужна Java (для Android) или Objective C (для iOS). Для мобильного приложения также необходимо будет реализовать сервер (см. предыдущий абзац).

Подытоживая вышесказанное: прежде чем выбирать язык программирования, определитесь с тем, где и как будет работать ваше приложение. Затем можете выбирать язык, подходящий для ваших задач и наиболее удобный для вас.

Answer (score 8):

Русский, и, возможно, английский — чтобы договориться о деньгах и нанять команду разработчиков, которая выполнит задание.

Comment: Вы забыли упомянуть о том что разработчикам понадобится фото автора размера А4, по другому ТЗ не составить.

Comment: Фото ни при чем. Задание формулируется двумя словами: «клонировать [BlaBlaCar](http://www.blablacar.ru/)»

Comment: Ахахахахаах норм ответ

Answer (score 0):

- Английский: для чтения документации,
- HTML/CSS/JavaScript: для фронтенда (браузер у клиента),
- SQL (СУБД, часто MySQL): хранение и выборка данных на сервере
- Python: для скриптов server-side бэкенда

  - хорошая система ООП, вменяемый синтаксис,
  - богатые сторонние библиотеки,
  - популярен в прикладной науке -- гугли примеры алгоритмов для логистики

Comment: Замечу, что именно из-за таких ответов (советующих конкретные технологии) подобные вопросы и закрываются. Потому что насоветовать таких стеков можно очень много, и все будут иметь право на жизнь. Этот не закрыт, потому что он очень стар, но вы своим ответом его подняли и процесс уже пошёл .-.